MapStruct problems with nested properties in combination with multiple parameters
I am trying to map from one nested object to another with some custom mappings, and I also need to add an additional field that is not present in the source object by using a second method parameter. I am getting either a compiler error when the target type uses constructor mapping or incomplete mapping when using mutable objects.
Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?
Some non-optimal workarounds:

Use mutable model & specify all fields

Need to specify for each identical fields
Mutable


Define additional helper method (see example below)

Extra work
Will get prohibitively expensive for deep nesting



My Model
record FromInner1(String a, String b, String c) {}
record FromInner2(String d, String e) {}
record FromOuter(FromInner1 inner1, FromInner2 inner2) {}

record ToInner1(String a, String b, String c) {}
record ToInner2(String d, String e, String additional) {}
record ToOuter(ToInner1 inner1, ToInner2 inner2) {}

My Mapper
@Mapping(target = "inner2.d", source = "fromOuter.inner2.d", qualifiedByName = "transform")
//@Mapping(target = "inner2.e", source = "fromOuter.inner2.e")
@Mapping(target = "inner2.additional", source = "additionalField")
ToOuter toOuter(FromOuter fromOuter, String additionalField);

@Named("transform")
default String transform(String original) {
  return original.trim().toUpperCase();
}

Compiler Errors
java: Property "d" has no write accessor in ToInner2 for target name "inner2.d".
java: Property "additional" has no write accessor in ToInner2 for target name "inner2.additional". 

Mutable Model
Using a mutable model, i.e., using the same fields, but making a no-args constructor, all-args constructor getters and setters for all the fields results in the following result test result
@Test
void toOuter() {
  assertThat(
        mapper.toOuter(
            new FromOuter(new FromInner1("a", "b", "c"), new FromInner2("    d    ", "e")),
            "additional"))
    .isEqualTo(new ToOuter(new ToInner1("a", "b", "c"), new ToInner2("D", "e", "additional")));
}

Expected :ToOuter(inner1=ToInner1(a=a, b=b, c=c), inner2=ToInner2(d=D, e=e, additional=additional))
Actual   :ToOuter(inner1=ToInner1(a=a, b=b, c=c), inner2=ToInner2(d=D, e=null, additional=additional))

Workaround
@Mapping(target = "inner2", expression = "java(toInner2(fromOuter.inner2(), additionalField))") //compiles, but does not change anything
ToOuter toOuter(FromOuter fromOuter, String additionalField);

@Named("transform")
default String transform(String original) {
  return original.trim().toUpperCase();
}

@Mapping(target = "d", source = "fromInner2.d", qualifiedByName = "transform")
@Mapping(target = "additional", source = "additionalField")
ToInner2 toInner2(FromInner2 fromInner2, String additionalField);

